# при добавлении в список значения int возвращается None

Tags: python, append

надо написать функцию, которая принимает список из чисел и возвращает словарь, где ключ - хеш-значение объекта, а значение сам объект. причем если в списке объекты повторяются, значение по ключу должно быть в виде списка.
для примера код:
**print (hash_as_key( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5] ))**
должен возвращать
**{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: [5, 5, 5]}**

почему то **d = t.append(objects [i] )** возвращает None вместо списка,  кто сталкивался с таким? в чем дело???

````
def hash_as_key(objects):
    list_hash = [hash(i) for i in objects]
    res_dict= dict()
    for i in range(len(list_hash)):
        try:
            t = res_dict[list_hash[i]]
            if type(t) == int:
                res_dict[list_hash[i]] = [t, objects[i]]
            if type(t) == list:
                d = t.append(objects[i])
                print(d)
                # -----> None
                res_dict[list_hash[i]] = d
        except:
            res_dict[list_hash[i]] = objects[i]
    return(res_dict) ```
````

Comment: `append` модифицирует список, соответственно ничего не возвращает.

Comment: вес поняла, спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `append()` добавляет элемент в массив и ничего не возвращает(соответственно является методом). Вам нужно лишь вновь обратиться к тому массиву, что бы увидеть что элемент был добавлен.